# word wrap data labels python-pptx

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

Is it possible to set word wrap to false all data labels in my chart?

I was trying to do plots[0].data_labels.format.text_frame.word_wrap = False but data_labels hasn't format property

Comment: Does the PowerPoint UI have an option for that? It's rare that `python-pptx` can do something the UI doesn't allow. If the UI supports it there has to be a way for the XML format to support it and we can look further.

Comment: Yes, it exists, 
1 - click on data labels
2 - button plus "+" 
3 - arrow data labels
4 - More options...
5 - text options (on top)
6 - text box
7 - Wrap text in shape (bottom)

https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/chartsdiagrams/images/more-chart-datalabels10.png

Comment: Try doing it on individual data labels using `plot.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.word_wrap` (increment the 0 values here for each series/point respectively) and see if that works.

Comment: Not works, when I declare it all data labels disappear

I've tryed
plot2.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.word_wrap = False
plot2.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.word_wrap = 0
plot2.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.word_wrap = True

Comment: Ok, well, next step is fairly major surgery then. You would adjust it by hand on an example presentation and then inspect the XML (before vs. after) to see where PowerPoint is storing that attribute. Then you would use `lxml` calls to modify the XML directly, starting from the closest element `python-pptx` could give you access to, like the series perhaps.

Comment: Thank you, I've found the attribute, is it <c:txPr><a:bodyPr wrap="square" /> to <c:txPr><a:bodyPr wrap="none" /> need only set wrap to none, do you have any idea how I can update this value in xml? @scanny

Answer (score 5):

Start with the `DataLabels` object. This is available on the  `.data_labels` attribute of a plot or a series. You might want to try both to see what behavior you get:

```
from pptx.text.text import TextFrame

# ---obtain reference to <c:dLbls> element in question---
data_labels = plot2.data_labels
dLbls = data_labels._element
# ---use its <c:txPr> child to create TextFrame object---
text_frame = TextFrame(dLbls.get_or_add_txPr(), None)
# ---turn off word-wrap in the usual way---
text_frame.word_wrap = False
```

This can be made more compact, I show it step-by-step here for clarity.

Comment: but this would only work I was trying to enable all data_labels right? Is there a way to this when I am following your approach from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371754/python-pptx-how-to-individually-hide-show-data-labels-in-graph)? Or any other easy way to disable wrapping but enable only some selected data labels?

Comment: You can try `series.points[i].data_label` which has this external interface: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.datalabel.DataLabel. It also has the internal method `._get_or_add_txPr()` which might suit. You'll have to experiment with behavior, PowerPoint doesn't always do what one might expect on data labels. Safest bet (if that doesn't "just work") would be to create a small example of what you want in PowerPoint and then inspect the XML for how it does it, then try to replicate XML using whatever means are available (including low-level lxml calls).