# python-pptx – How to individually hide/show data labels in graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I would like to be able to flexibly show or hide data labels in a stacked bar chart.

I thought this would have been possible by accessing an individual datalabel as such:
`plot.series[0].points[1].data_label` and then assigning its `has_text_frame` attribute to `True` or `False`, but this isn't working.

My use case is more complex than the below, but was trying to get it work with a simple example. If possible please show me how it can be done with the code snippet attached below.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
x = ['one','two','three', 'four']
y = [7.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.0]
specs = {
    'height': Cm(7.82),
    'width': Cm(14.8),
    'left': Cm(2.53),
    'top': Cm(5.72)}

data = ChartData()
data.categories = x
label_values = tuple(y)
data.add_series('Series 1', label_values)
frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, specs['left'],
                               specs['top'], specs['width'],
                               specs['height'], data)
chart = frame.chart
plot = chart.plots[0]

# Attempt at showing all labels except for one
plot.has_data_labels = True
plot.series[0].points[1].data_label.has_text_frame =False

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

Comment: The first step with this sort of thing is to see if it is possible using the PowerPoint application. If it is not possible, this is a strong (but not absolutely conclusive) indicator that the file format does not support that operation. If it _is_ possible in the application, the procedure often gives hints and the XML PowerPoint emits will give direct indication of how it is accomplished. That doesn't by itself mean `python-pptx` has API support for it, but it tells us exactly where to look.

Comment: Thanks for your help @scanny. It is possible in PowerPoint. You simply right click on the series you want and press `add data labels`. How can I get the XML powerpoint emits?

Comment: If it's a clustered and not a stacked chart you can also: right click on the point->format data labels->check/uncheck value to toggle displaying the data label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the approach you want is to turn them *on* individually rather than to turn them *off* individually. I believe PowerPoint supports both approaches, but `python-pptx` will only support the "add" method, if it does that.

Try something like this:

```
plot = chart.plots[0]
# ---best if data-labels don't appear by default
# ---turn them off, but only if they already show
# ---since it might disrupt what comes next
# plot.has_data_labels = False
plot.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.text = "Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this for a similar use case -- ***hiding data labels when the value is 0.***

I believe this answer will be useful for this same situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657081