# Set data labels text frame wrap to false – python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am asking a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353954/word-wrap-data-labels-python-pptx), except that the answer submitted does not work for me. I would like to toggle the data_labels' "Wrap text in shape" button from the powerpoint UI via python-pptx. The linked answer ends up removing the data labels altogether instead. I am using the latest python-pptx version (0.6.18).

Here is a simple example to replicate:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm
from pptx.text.text import TextFrame

# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
x = ['one','two','three', 'four']
y = [['diff',
  [1,
   2,
   3,
   4,
]],
 ]
specs = {
    'height': Cm(7.82),
    'width': Cm(14.8),
    'left': Cm(2.53),
    'top': Cm(5.72)}
data = ChartData()
data.categories = x
data.add_series('diff', [j for j in y[0][1]])

frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, specs['left'], specs['top'], 
    specs['width'], specs['height'], data
)
plot = frame.chart.plots[0]
plot.has_data_labels = True
data_labels = plot.series[0].data_labels
dLbls = data_labels._element
# ---use its <c:txPr> child to create TextFrame object---
text_frame = TextFrame(dLbls.get_or_add_txPr(), None)
# ---turn off word-wrap in the usual way---
text_frame.wrap = False

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the second to last line should be `text_frame.word_wrap = False`, not `.wrap`; that's my mistake on the earlier answer (now fixed).

Also change this line:

```
data_labels = plot.series[0].data_labels
```

to:

```
data_labels = plot.data_labels
```

And I think you'll get what you're looking for.